# Jquery get highest value of specific object from seperate arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I tried to find an answer here but I can't find a working solution. 
I have a function that create arrays with some product delivery data in it, like so:

I have two products in a cart, with html like so:

```
<div class="prod" data-pid="41853029" data-vid="79380299" data-qty="1">....<div>
<div class="prod" data-pid="41853029" data-vid="79380296" data-qty="3">....<div>
```

Next I grab all the info from the products in the cart, like so:

```
$(function(){
  $('.prod').each(function(){  
   var vid = $(this).data('vid')
   var url = 'link-to-api/api/stock/'+$(this).data('pid')+'?secret=secret&quantity='+$(this).data('qty')
   getAllItems(url, vid)
  });
});
```

The above data is send to the function `getAllItems`. In this function there's a JSON call to an API from a supplier. From here I want to return an array with two other arrays that contain the new data from the API. Something along the lines of this:

```
 // "main" array
 [
  // array with product data for product 1
  [
    {
      "id": 79380299,
      "dt": 1,
      "dtt": "Voor 17:00 uur = morgen in huis",
      "co": "17:00",
      "sid": 5
    }
  ],
  // array with product data for product 2
  [
    {
      "id": 79380296,
      "dt": 3,
      "dtt": "Voor 15:00 uur besteld, over 3 werkdagen in huis",
      "co": "15:00",
      "sid": 5
    }
  ]
 ]
```

When I have this "main" array I want to filter this array on the value `dt` (which means delivery time). After filtering I want to send a single array with the highest `dt` value to a new function. I tried something along the lines of below code:

```
 function getAllItems(url, vid){

  var matched_variant = []
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data.variants, function(i, variant){
     if(variant.id == vid){
      matched_variant.push({
        id: variant.id, 
        dt: variant.deliveryTimeInDays, 
        dtt: variant.deliveryTime, 
        co: variant.cutOffTime, 
        sid: variant.supplier_id
      });
     } 
    });
  }).done(function(){

  let matched = matched_variant
  let highest = {dt: 0};

  matched.forEach((arr, arrIndex) => {
    arr.forEach(dtObj => {
      let dt = parseInt(dtObj.dt)
      if (dt > highest.dt) {
        highest = dtObj;
      }
    })
  });
  let highestDTArray = [highest];
  setDeliveryDate(array_with_highest_dt_value)
  });
}
```

To be complete, JSON data:

```
{
  "id": 41853029,
  "variants": {
    "79380290": {
      "id": 79380290,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "no",
      "levelLocal": 0,
      "levelSupplier": 0,
      "deliveryTime": "out of stock",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": -1
    },
    "79380293": {
      "id": 79380293,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "no",
      "levelLocal": 0,
      "levelSupplier": 0,
      "deliveryTime": "out of stock",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": -1
    },
    "79380296": {
      "id": 79380296,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "supplier",
      "levelLocal": 1,
      "levelSupplier": 250,
      "deliveryTime": "Three days",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": 3
    },
    "79380299": {
      "id": 79380299,
      "supplier_id": 5,
      "on_stock": "supplier",
      "levelLocal": 2,
      "levelSupplier": 250,
      "deliveryTime": "One day",
      "cutOffTime": "15:00",
      "deliveryTimeInDays": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Two questions:

1) With above code I'm struggeling to create the `main` array with the two other arrays in it. How do I create a single array with the product data arrays in it?

2) How can I compare that `dt` value and return it so it can be send to function `setDeliveryDate(array_with_highest_dt_value)` ?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright hopefully this edit is the one, first off it looks like you have an async problem now, you want to wait for all the requests to come back before proceeding.

I handle this with the `numReqFinished` variable, you can see after each response comes back I increase that number. When it reaches the number of products you have in your loop, we know we have a response for each product, then we will call `getHighestDTFromArray()` to proceed.

I added `[]` around the `matched_variant.push()` in `getAllItems` to hopefully get the result you wanted for question #1

`getAllItems()` pretty much stays as I originally wrote it.

Some of this might need to be tweaked as I haven't tested it, but the idea should be sufficient enough to help get you moving.

**Note**: its important to [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the dt value before comparing it too- since its stored as a string.

For example:

```js
var matched_variant = [];
var numReqFinished = 0;

$(function() {
  $('.prod').each(function() {
    var vid = $(this).data('vid')
    var url = 'link-to-api/api/stock/' + $(this).data('pid') + '?secret=secret&quantity=' + $(this).data('qty');
    getAllItems(url, vid, $('.prod').length)
  });
});

function getAllItems(url, vid, totalProds) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    numReqFinished++;

    $.each(data.variants, function(i, variant) {
      if (variant.id == vid) {
        matched_variant.push([{
          id: variant.id,
          dt: variant.deliveryTimeInDays,
          dtt: variant.deliveryTime,
          co: variant.cutOffTime,
          sid: variant.supplier_id
        }]);
      }
    });
    if (totalProds === numReqFinished) {
      getHighestDTFromArray();
    }
  })
}

function getHighestDTFromArray() {
  let matched = matched_variant
  let highest = {
    dt: 0
  };

  matched.forEach((arr, arrIndex) => {
    arr.forEach(dtObj => {
      let dt = parseInt(dtObj.dt)
      if (dt > highest.dt) {
        highest = dtObj;
      }
    })
  });
  let highestDTArray = [highest];
  setDeliveryDate(array_with_highest_dt_value)
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="prod" data-pid="41853029" data-vid="79380299" data-qty="1">....
</div>

<div class="prod" data-pid="41853029" data-vid="79380296" data-qty="3">....
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but this returns not a single array but multiple. When you run "run code snippet" you'll see what I mean. What I'm looking for is a single array with data from the one with the highest `dt`. Perhaps I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what an array is. My solution provides 1 array with 2 object inside it (the 2 objects are from the inner array with the highest dt)

Comment: do you mean you want an array with 1 obj in it? The highest dt obj?

Comment: Yes I said it the wrong way indeed. Sorry. What I mentioned was that there should be one object with the highest `dt` value in this created array. Then I can send this created array to a new function.

Comment: @Meules alright I updated the example to give you the the single highest dt obj inside an array.

Comment: Excellent!! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!! +1 for mentioning the string instead of integer :)

Comment: glad to help! no problem

Comment: It seems I can't get it top work anyway :( I said there was an array created with two other arrays in it. However there are two seperate arrays created. When I use your manually created `matched` the code works. However I can't get it to work with those two seperate arrays. Do you have perhaps any suggestions? Your example really helped me so I'm hoping you can help me another time :)

Comment: @Meules do you only have 2 arrays? Or a dynamic amount? I updated my answer for only having 2 arrays you can get away with that code. If you have more than 2 arrays I would try a different approach.

Comment: Thx man! The amount of arrays is indeed dynamically. It's based on the amount of products in a cart. I tried last weekend to work with `promises` but that's a bit difficult to understand for me :) If you could help me that would make my day (actually last 10 days :))

Comment: Sure how are the multiple arrays returned? Do you have a single variable with all the arrays? What is `matched_variant` exactly?

Comment: The code you updated in your question indeed only returns 1 array with 1 object in it.

Comment: I think the problem may be that the function is called inside the `$('.prod').each(function(){` which obviously calls the function twice for two products. Therefore it also returns two arrays, right?

Comment: it would call `getAllItems()` twice, which will call `setDeliveryDate(array_with_highest_dt_value)` twice as well

Comment: If you create a more complete snippet with your html and it shows a specific problem you can explain- I would be able to help further.

Comment: I've updated my question with the complete code. And I splitted my question in two :) That filtering at question 2 I've added to be more clear. If I could yuse your original code there that would be more then fine offcourse. I hope you can help, thx!

Comment: @Meules alright I did 1 more edit, hopefully this helps you enough :)

Comment: You sir are a live saver :) Tested and works!! Kudos for your clear explaination... Never thought you could handle `async` request like this. That's why I started reading about promises.  Man you made my day!!

Comment: Bounty will be awarded in 19 hours SO syas

Comment: glad I could help! There are many ways to handle async requests like this. But this was the quickest and easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the value of dt with a static value.

```
var biggest= Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
var array_with_highest_dt_value;
$.each(matched, function(){
 $.each(this, function(i, variant){
   if(variant.dt > biggest) {
      biggest = variant.dt;
      // Put a reference for later
      array_with_highest_dt_value= this;
   }      
 });
});
setDeliveryDate(array_with_highest_dt_value)
```

Comment: Whan I try your solution I get an empty array back.

Comment: Sorry I said empty but I meant `undefined`

Comment: Please see updated answer. I removed the `[` & `]` from the `each` iterator on the "matched"